# How to create "aws logs put-subscription-filter --log-group-name" using tags from log group tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

AWS CLI: [PutSubscriptionFilter - Amazon CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html)

I am trying to use tags from a log group in `put-subscription-filter` and I do not know how to create the string for `--log-group-name`.

Here's the tagging of a log group:

```
aws logs tag-log-group \
...
  --tags Application=TestApp,OwnerContact=somebody,Type=Lambda,Service=test
```

Here's the Issue:

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter \
   --log-group-name **???????**
   ....
```

Please provide an answer using tags: Application, Service

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to define the filter, or the name of the log?

Comment: I am trying to identify all log groups that have one or more tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [put-subscription-filter — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-subscription-filter.html), the `--log-group-name` option only takes a string (the name of the log group).

It is not possible to use a tag as the name for `put-subscription-filter`.

Comment: The API documentation specifies a pattern.
Also, trying to figure out how to make use of tags.  Thought I could use them with the AWS CLI.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html

logGroupName
The name of the log group.

Type: String

Length Constraints: Minimum length of 1. Maximum length of 512.

Pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+

Required: Yes

Comment: Strings are only accepted as values and not regular expressions.
Also, AWS support stated:
The purpose of tagging is to categorize your log groups. But you cannot make an API call to get the list of log group names based on the tags.

So, the tags are pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is: **identify all log groups that have one or more tags** (presumably specified tags, rather than just a count of tags).

You can do this via:

- Obtain a list of logs groups with [describe-log-groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-groups.html)
- For each log group returned, call [list-tags-log-group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/list-tags-log-group.html)
- Look at the tags returned to determine whether the log group is of interest

This would be easier to implementing in a scripting language such as Python (using the AWS boto3 SDK).